# I need all possible settings between Tune Pre V2 + Focusrite Scarlett 2I2

Tags: studio, pre-amp

Recently I have bought a Tube pre V2 and I will use it with a Focusrite Scarlett 2i2.

I need to know how to set the gain knob of the input of the interface when receiving the signal from the preamp. I need to know how to set the line/instrument switch of the interface input when receiving the signal of the preamp either if it is from xlr balanced or from unbalanced 1\4’’.

If you can help me writing all the possible configuration between this 2 devices I will thank you so much, because in the manual there is not that info of this combines devices.

Comment: Geez, no need to shout in the question title. And yes, writing in all caps is considered shouting and it is generally discouraged wherever you post, be it social media, a forum, or a Q and A message board like Stack Exchange because instead of bringing attention(which is probably your intent), it makes people think you are rude and ignore that post. If a poster repeatedly does this, the readers will probably ignore all the posts from that poster, even when the poster stops shouting in the posts.